# GAE python: What should I use for an operation that last for around 3 mins?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to get some data with app engine using urlfetch. The operation lasts for around 3 mins when doing it locally.

However, I've tried to use cron to do it but it returns errors with an F2 instance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267

This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time.
```

So my question is what should I use to do this? Anyway I can fix it using cron or do I use module or taskqueue or background_thread to do it? Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: For GAE I'd start with taskqueue. Outside of GAE,  threads would he enough if you're just trying to avoid blocking the ui thread.

Comment: Thanks. Let me give it a try!  I was thinking about threads too. But it requires to use module for using background_thread in GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [deferred library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred):

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

def get_data(a, b, c=None):
    logging.info("Doing something expensive!")
    # Do your work here

# Somewhere else
deferred.defer(do_something_expensive, "Hello, world!", 42, c=True)
```

By default you'll have [10 minutes to finish execution](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#task_deadlines), but you could improve it if needed.

Also remember to add this to your app.yaml:

```
builtins:
- deferred: on
```